# Props of path "/" is not rendering on site?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Output:

> [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
>
> index.js:1 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

App.js Code:

```js
import Header from "./MyComponents/Header";
import { Todos } from "./MyComponents/Todos";
import { Footer } from "./MyComponents/Footer";
import { AddToDo } from "./MyComponents/AddTodo";
import { About } from "./MyComponents/About";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

<Router>
  <Header title="My Todos List" searchBar={false} />
  <Routes>
    <Route
      path ="/"
      element={() => {
        return (
          <>
            <AddToDo addTodo={addTodo} />
            <Todos todos={todos} onDelete={onDelete} />
          </>
        )
      }}
    />
    <Route path="/about"
      element ={<About />}
    />
  </Routes>
  <Footer />
</Router>
```

Comment: Are you using ReactDOM.render() to actually render the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that in RRDv6 the `element` prop is expecting JSX (*i.e. a `React.ReactElement`*), not a function returning JSX.

[Routes & Route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route)

> ```
> interface RouteProps {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   element?: React.ReactElement | null;
>   index?: boolean;
>   path?: string;
> }
> ```

```
<Route
  path ="/"
  element={() => { // <-- this is a function, not a ReactElement
    return (
      <>
        <AddToDo addTodo={addTodo} />
        <Todos todos={todos} onDelete={onDelete} />
      </>
    )
  }}
/>
```

Render the JSX directly.

```
<Route
  path ="/"
  element={(
    <> // <-- now a ReactElement
      <AddToDo addTodo={addTodo} />
      <Todos todos={todos} onDelete={onDelete} />
    </>
  )}
/>
```

Alternatively, you could also abstract the anonymous React component definition into a named React component and render ***as JSX***.

```
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <AddToDo addTodo={addTodo} />
      <Todos todos={todos} onDelete={onDelete} />
    </>
  )
};
```

...

```
<Route
  path ="/"
  element={<Home />} // <-- now a ReactElement
/>
```